# Can't get any data when i scrape with scrapy/splash

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

im trying to scrape data from airbnb so im using scrapy-splash for the javascript but i can't take any data ! i can take data from it with scrapy-selenium but its slow and sometimes there is some data missing i have to repeat the scrapy crawl to get it. so i used scrapy-splash in another page 'https://www.livecoin.net/en' which countains javascript and it worked perfectly but when i use it on this page with the same code but i change url and tags it don't work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
class CoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'airbnbtest'

script = '''
    function main(splash, args)
        splash.private_mode_enabled = false
        url = args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(5))
        splash:set_viewport_full()
        return splash:html()
    end

'''
def start_requests(self):
    yield SplashRequest(url="https://fr.airbnb.com/rooms/908350?adults=1&check_in=2020-12-15&check_out=2020-12-19&source_impression_id=p3_1606413122_qj9zG9UIi4WW%2FKUy&guests=1", callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute", args={
        'lua_source': self.script
    })

def parse(self, response):
   a=response.xpath('(//div[@class="_1qsawv5"]//text())[1]').get()
   print(a)
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'worldometers'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['worldometers.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'worldometers.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,}
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,}
 DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
 EED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'
 SPLASH_URL='http://localhost:8050'
 from shutil import which
```

Comment: What information do you want to get with your XPath? There is no `//span[@class="_1qsawv5"]` on that page for me.

Comment: i mean "(//div[@class="_1qsawv5"])[1]" sry  i changed the code while i am testing something else !! still don't work